# Cascading Parameters in Report Builder 3 for a Many-to-Many relationship dataset

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I got a request to create a cascading parameter for Projects in a dataset like this:

Project     Manager 
    A          Person 1
    A          Person 2
    B          Person 1

etc...

When the user chooses a particular manager, this works fine, but the user can also choose all the managers, in which case there would be multiples of the same Project in the parameter drop down list...

I'm very new to SQL, so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think you're looking for a `group by project` or `select distinct` for the second query.

Comment: `select distinct` isn't going to work because the first row and second row are distinct (in the example I outlined), and I don't think `group by` will work either, as Manager cannot be aggregated into anything meaningful. If I'm not understanding correctly, please elaborate.

Comment: you wouldn't include the manager column...it'd just be `select project from ... where manager_id in (1,2) group by project`

Comment: Oh, thanks! It works! If you want, you can write up an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a `group by project` or `select distinct` for the second query.

```
select project from ... where manager_id in (1,2) group by project
```